# Argument param to login to SSH with password on Windows 10

Tags: windows, ssh, windows-10

In *nix, the `sshpass` package is used with the `-p` param to login with password.

What is the equivalent command for Windows?

Answer (score 1):

You can pre-configure username/password with the [Credential Manager](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026814/windows-accessing-credential-manager).

Windows will populate Credential Manager himself when you choose to "Rember the password" in various login windows.

However, you can add entries manually, and Windows will use them when you want to connect to the matching server/protocol.

Comment: Thank you, but I was trying to write a bat file for the ssh so I'm hoping that there will be such a command.